# If $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = 0$, and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x) = \infty$, show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)^{g(x)} = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

For some reason, the answer I get is $1$. 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow a}   f(x)^{g(x)}
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}     g(x)  \ln[f(x)]\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}   \ln[f(x)] / (1/ {g(x)}) \quad\text{gives $\infty/\infty$, so by L'hospital}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow a} (1/f(x)) / ( -1/ g(x)^{2})\\
&= 0
\end{align*}
and $e^{0} = 1$.

However, according to the textbook, the answer should be  $0$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $[1/g(x)]$ approaches to 0 not to $\infty$. Also $ d/dx[ ln(f(x))] = f'(x)/f(x)$

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}   f(x)^{g(x)}=(?!!) \lim_{x\rightarrow a}     g(x)  \ln[f(x)]$ Why!!

Comment: You don't know if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable. So how do you apply L'hospital?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let  $y=f(x)^{g(x)} \\\implies ln(y)=g(x)ln(f(x))$

Then,

$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}  ln(y)\\=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}     g(x)  \ln(f(x))\\=\infty\cdot(-\infty)\\=-\infty$

So,

$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}   f(x)^{g(x)}\\=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}     y \\=e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow a}     ln(y)}\\=0$

---

Provided $f(x)>0$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need l'Hospital to calculate your limit. $\ln f(x)$ goes to $-\infty$ and $g(x)$ goes to $+\infty$ so $\ln f(x)g(x)$ goes to $-\infty$. Therefore $f(x)^{g(x)}$ goes to $\exp(-\infty)=0$.

Your series of equalities is wrong, since at a moment you took a logarithm out of the blue.